# self-service mapping tools

Tags: carto, business-intelligence

I've been looking for mapping software that will allow non-GIS-trained staff, or clients, to create their own maps. For example, CartoDB provides hosted mapping with a web interface that's reasonably straightforward. StatPlanet also aims at enabling end users to create their own maps and tweak them via a Flash program.

Both of these tools have good features, but also have some limitations. I would like to hear what other alternatives are out there. I'm especially looking for cross-platform ease of use, flexibility of coloring schemes (e.g. bi-polar progressions), and ease of importing custom data.